# JavaScript remote click

Tags: javascript, click, dom-events

I am trying to bind two elements on a Web page, so that when I click on one, it also triggers the click on the other. For example I have data presented in both a table and a pie chart, and clicking on the chart should have the same effect as clicking directly on the data in the table.

[Edit] I need it as a generic utility, as I don't necessarily know what action the original element will trigger.

How can I achieve this, cross-browser, in plain JavaScript?

What I am looking for has some similarities with the jQuery `click()` method, except that:

- I am not using jQuery
- I don't need to trigger the click programmatically, the user will do it

It is also similar to the JavaScript `click()`, but `click()` doesn't work cross-browser.

Comment: you want to call two functions on 1 button ?

Comment: No, the opposite: have the second "button" call the same function as the first "button". But when I write my code (plugin) I don't know in advance the function that the first button will trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated code. This should do it. When you click the second element, call the first element's click event and pass in the first button as `this`

```
<div onclick="alert(this.getAttribute('id'));" id="b1" >Hi!!</div>
<div  id="b2" >Hi!! 2</div>
```

With this code:

```
document.getElementById("b2").onclick = function() { 
 document.getElementById("b1").onclick.call(document.getElementById("b1"));
};
```

Also in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RVAMm/26/

Comment: I don't necessarily know or have control on commonFunction. I have tried to clarify my question. For example the chart could be built using progressive enhancement.

Comment: @Christophe so you basically have element 1 that goes to some external click event (who knows what) and you want to tap into that when element 2 is clicked?

Comment: Yes! And ideally, "this" should refer to the original element (as if the user had directly clicked on the table).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```
theElementYouWantToClick.onClick()
```